# Possible: Animate Jquery slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

Is it possible to animate the slider from jQuery? so that if I press the button the inner of the slider should move slower (for example 300ms) and also NOT to react to mouse click and slide?

This is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/gm4tG/5/

HTML:

```
<div id='slider' class='sliderBar'></div>
<button>Remove 10%</button>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#slider {
    height:20px;
    max-height:20px;
}
.sliderBar-progress {
    background:rgb(0, 255, 0);

}
```

JS:

```
$('#slider').sliderBar({
    start: 100,
    onChange: function (val) {
        var red = 0,
            green = 0;
        if (val >= 50) {
            red = 255 - Math.round(((val - 50) / 50) * 255);
            green = 255;
        } else {
            red = 255;
            green = Math.round(((val) / 50) * 255);

        }
        $('.sliderBar-progress').css({
            background: "rgb(" + red + "," + green + ",0)"
        });
    }
});

$('button').on('click', function () {
 $('#slider').setsliderBar($('#slider').getsliderBar()-10, true);
});
```

Thank You very much!

Comment: what do you mean by "and NOT to react to mouse click and slide"

Comment: @IrvinZhan it should not be affected by mouse drag or click.. (so the actual slider ability should be disabled).. it should be just a non clickable bar wich decreases when the button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sliderBar-progress {
    background:rgb(0, 255, 0);
    transition-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 5s; /* for Safari */
}
```

This property is supported in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer 10, Opera and Safari.

[Revised JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g2N2m/4/)

Comment: can the mouse interaction be disabled.. (so the actual slider ability should be disabled).. it should be just a non clickable bar wich decreases when the button is clicked it should not be affected by mouse drag or click.. (so the actual slider ability should be disabled)..